# css / jquery code to hide article if the name is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I hide a article if the name is empty.
I am using some articles on my site to display certain information.

```
<article name="<?php echo $name[0];?>"> 
<p>Content</p> 
<article>
```

How can I hide that article if the name is empty or there is another article with the same name?

Comment: use this: `$("article[name='']").hide()` when the name is empty.

Comment: Do you need the hidden article to still appear in the page's source ?  If no, just discard it using php `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (http://jsfiddle.net/v6at2rhj/):

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var articles = [];
    $("article[name]").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("name") == "")
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else
        {
            if (articles.indexOf($(this).attr("name")) > -1 )
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else
            {
                articles.push($(this).attr("name"));
            }
        }           
    });
});
```

On page load it finds all articles with the `name` attribute (empty or not). Then it iterates over them. If the attribute is empty it will hide the element. If not it will check if the name of the element is in the `articles` array. If so hide the element, if not add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('article[name=""]'), function(article) {
    article.style.display = 'none';
});
```

This code will look for each article with a blank name attribute, and set it's display to none, effectively hiding it. You could go a step further and remove it from the DOM completely, if you wish.

Comment: This is nice. I like plain JavaScript code +1. However the OP requested jQuery and also articles with the same name to be removed.

Comment: He did not explicitly ask for jQuery; he only tagged it so, even in the title, which is weird. I'm currently editing with the full solution

Comment: Still I like plain JavaScript. I think css / jQuery code in the title is kind of a request.

Answer (score 0):

you should give the article a class for example 
and then add this code to your javascript

```
 $(.article-class).on('each',function() {

    if ($(this).attr('name')=='')

    {
      $(this).hide()
    }
    )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("article[name]:has(p:contains('Content'))").hide();
```

```js
$("article[name]:has(p:contains('Content'))").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article name="<?php echo $name[0];?>"> 
<p>Content</p> 
<article>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, but what if the content is just a place holder. It also doesn't hide empty names, It simply hides all articles with a name attribute and a p tag containing content

Comment: @Mouser Utilizing `html` at OP . If a filter is available , could be used to select desired element . Here , `<p>Content</p>` provided , used as filter . Though could also use an empty element as filter . Do the other  elements having a `name` attribute also not have a `value` ("empty") ? OP also mentions that another element may have same `name` attribute _"or there is another article with the same name"_ . Just utilized available child element / `html` content at OP to select / filter . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('article').each(function (i) {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var articles = $("article[name='"+ name +"']:visible")
    if(name == "" || articles.length > 1)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
})
```

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3x6tfbkb/3/).